# Traversing an array to find the second largest element in linear time

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Is there a way in linear time by which we can find which is the second largest element of an array ? 
Array elements can be positive, negative or zero.
Elements can be repetitive.
No STLs allowed.
Python can be used.

*Solution : Sort the array and take the second element but **Sorting not allowed***

Modification : By definition second largest element will be the one which is numerically smaller. Like if we have

Arr = {5,5,4,3,1}
Then second largest is 4

**Addition**
Lets say if i want to generalize the question to kth largest and complexity less than linear like nlogn, what can be the solution.

Comment: Why in linear time when you can have it in `n long n` time?

Comment: If the maximum value is duplicated, does it count as the second largest value, or are we to select the one below it?  That is, in a list `3,4,5,5` is `4` or `5` the second largest element?

Comment: 4 is considered as second largest element.

Comment: @user1344784 please suggest how can it be done in `n logn` thanks.

Comment: @Codeanu `O(n) < O(n long n)`

Comment: Your selected answer from the example you added is different from your "solution" of sorting the array and taking the second element.

Comment: can someone explain why i have been given one vote down ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a true O(n) algorithm, and want to find nth largest element in array then you should use quickselect (it's basically quicksort where you throw out the partition that you're not interested in), and the below is a great writeup, with the runtime analysis:

http://pine.cs.yale.edu/pinewiki/QuickSelect

Comment: @Codeanu : Glad yo know it help u

Comment: The link in the answer appears to be broken. Here's a wiki article on the quickselect algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Comment: Also, quickselect is not O(n); it's O(n^2) because it has poor worst case performance. Further it uses a sorting algorithm but the question says sorting is not allowed so this seems like a violation of the problem constraints.

Answer (score 7):

You can, this is the pseudo algorithm:

```
max = 2max = SMALLEST_INT_VALUE;

for element in v:
   if element > max:
      2max = max;
      max = element;

  else if element > 2max:
      2max = element;
```

2max is the value you are looking for.

The algorithm won't return a correct value for particular cases, such as an array where its elements are equal.

Comment: I don't think you need to swap... 2max = max is enough, since you're overwriting max on the following line. also, in the second line you're assuming that v[1] < v[0]: you should probably fix that...

Comment: This fails is the first two elements are the same value and the maximum value in the list.

Comment: You are right. AFAICS, initializing both with the smallest integer value one could expect should suffice, isn't it?

Answer (score 7):

Go through the array, keeping 2 memory slots to record the 2 largest elements seen so far.  Return the smaller of the two.

.... is there anything tricky about this question that I can't see?

Comment: If this is indeed the same algorithm as Simone, it would also fail if the first two items are the same value and the max value.

Comment: If a list contains the three elements {0, 1, 1}, what is the second largest element?  It's still 1.  Try sorting such a list and taking the second element from the top.

Comment: I guess that depends on the definition of second largest then. I've added a comment and removed my downvote.

Comment: @bdares lets say if i want to generalize the question to kth largest, this algorithm may not be appropriate.

Comment: @Codeanu, then yes, quickselect is certainly the way to go. But that's not what you asked originally. I thought of both quickselect and this method when I saw the question, but if you really only wanted just the 2nd largest (or there abouts) then this is a much simpler thing to implement than quickselect.

Comment: @Justin Peelyes certainly it is.

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo code:

```
int max[2] = { array[0], array[1] }

if(max[1] < max[0]) swap them

for (int i = 2; i < array.length(); i++) {
  if(array[i] >= max[0]) max[1] = max[0]; max[0] = array[i]
  else if(array[i] >= max[1]) max[1] = array[i];
}
```

Now, max array contains the max 2 elements.

Comment: You're not checking which is greater of array[0] and array[1].

Comment: Tyler Crompton, yes you are right. I forgot to mention that. I will do it right away!

Answer (score 1):

- create a temporary array of size 3,
- copy first 3 elements there,
- sort the temporary array,
- replace the last one in the temporary array with the 4th element from the source array,
- sort the temporary array,
- replace the last one in the temporary array with the 5th element from the source array,
- sort the temporary array,
- etc.

Sorting array of size 3 is constant time and you do that once for each element of the source array, hence linear overall time.

Comment: Costly linear time, but linear indeed. You should mention you want to sort in *descending* order if you are to replace the last item all the time.  Would this also suffer from selecting the max if there are duplicate max values (depending on whether a duplicate counts as max).

Answer (score 1):

Yep. You tagged this as C/C++ but you mentioned you could do it in Python. Anyway, here is the algorithm:

1. Create the array (obviously).
2. If the first item is greater than the second item, set first variable to the first item and second variable to second item. Otherwise, do vise-versa.
3. Loop through all the items (except the first two).
4. If the item from the array is greater than first variable, set second variable to first variable and first variable to the item. Else if the item is greater than second variable set second variable to the item.

The second variable is your answer.

```
list = [-1,6,9,2,0,2,8,10,8,-10]

if list[0] > list[1]:
        first = list[0]
        second = list[1]
else:
        first = list[1]
        second = list[0]

for i in range(2, len(list)):
        if list[i] > first:
                first, second = list[i], first
        elif list[i] > second:
                second = list[i]

print("First:", first)
print("Second:", second)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// assuming that v is the array and length is its length
int m1 = max(v[0], v[1]), m2 = min(v[0], v[1]);

for (int i=2; i<length; i++) {
  if (likely(m2 >= v[i]))
    continue;
  if (unlikely(m1 < v[i]))
    m2 = m1, m1 = v[i];
  else
    m2 = v[i];
}
```

The result you need is in m2 (likely and unlikely are macros defined as [here](http://kerneltrap.org/node/4705) for performance purposes, you can simply remove them if you don't need them).

Answer (score 0):

I think the other answers have not accounted for the fact that in an array like [0, 1, 1], the second largest is 0 (according to the updated problem definition). Furthermore, all mentions of quickselect are not O(n) but rather O(n^2) and are doing much more work than necessary (on top of which that is a sorting algorithm which the problem statement disallowed). Here is a very similar algorithm to Simone's but updated to return the second largest unique element:

```
def find_second(numbers):
    top = numbers[0]
    second = None

    for num in numbers[1:]:
        if second is None:
            if num < top: second = num
            elif num > top:
                second = top
                top = num
        else:
            if num > second:
                if num > top:
                    second = top
                    top = num
                elif num < top: second = num

    if second is not None: return second
    return top

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "The second largest is %d" % find_second([1,2,3,4,4,5,5])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Second larger element and its position(s)
    int[] tab = { 12, 1, 21, 12, 8, 8, 1 };
    int[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(tab, tab.length);
    int secMax = 0;
    Arrays.sort(tmp);
    secMax = tmp[tmp.length - 2];
    System.out.println(secMax);
    List<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
        if (tab[i] == secMax) {
            positions.add(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(positions);
```